# Could not translate MS Sql query to Hibernate @Query

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, hibernate, jpql

I have the following MS SQL Query that works perfectly.

```
select u.id, u.username, r2.authority, em.hrt02_first_name, em.hrt02_last_name from users as u
    inner join group_members gm
        on u.id = gm.user_id
    inner join groups g
        on gm.group_id = g.id
    inner join group_authorities ga
        on ga.group_id = g.id
    inner join roles r2
        on ga.role_id = r2.id
    inner join hrt02_employee_name em
        on em.id = u.id
where u.username = 'john'
```

The output is as follows

```
+----+----------+------------+------------------+-----------------+
| id | username | authority  | hrt02_first_name | hrt02_last_name |
+----+----------+------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 1  | john     | ROLE_ADMIN | fname            | lname           |
+----+----------+------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 1  | john     | ROLE_USER  | fname            | lname           |
+----+----------+------------+------------------+-----------------+
```

But When I tried to convert it to Hibernate Query or `@Query(..., nativeQuery=true) it throws exception. (Failed to Lazy Initialize and Path expected for join).

This is the My Schema Design

```
@Entity
public class Users {
    // id, username omitted

    @ManyToMany
      @JoinTable(name="group_members", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id"), inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
    private List<Groups> groups;
}

@Entity
public class Groups {
    // id omitted
    @ManyToMany
      @JoinTable(name="group_authorities", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id"), inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
    private List<Roles> roles;
}

@Entity
public class Roles {
    // id omitted, authority
}

@Entity
public class Hrt02EmployeeName {
    // id, firstname, lastname omitted
}
```

### Update 1 - Queries I've tried,

All examples here throws an error, but if you written them in native query and run them, they works as expected. So, It's probably me not knowing how to convert it from nativeQuery to Hibernate Query.

```
public interface UsersRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, Long> {
    @Query(value =
            "select * from users as u" +
            "    inner join group_members gm" +
            "        on u.id = gm.user_id" +
            "    inner join groups g" +
            "        on gm.group_id = g.id" +
            "    inner join group_authorities ga" +
            "        on ga.group_id = g.id" +
            "    inner join roles r2" +
            "        on ga.role_id = r2.id" +
            " inner join hrt02_employee_name em" +
            "  on em.id = u.id" +
            "  where u.username = :qryusername", nativeQuery = true)
    public Users findRoleByUsername(@Param("qryusername") String username);

    @Query("select distinct u.username, r2.authority from Users as u " +
            " inner join group_members gm " +
            "  on u.id = gm.user_id " +
            " inner join Groups g " +
            "  on gm.group_id = g.id " +
            " inner join group_authorities ga " +
            "  on ga.group_id = g.id " +
            " inner join Roles r2 " +
            "  on ga.role_id = r2.id" +
            " inner join hrt02_employee_name em" +
            "  on em.id = u.id" +
            " where u.username = :username")
    public Users findRoleByUsername(@Param("username") String username);

    @Query(value =
            "select u from Users u" +
            " inner join GroupMembers gm" +
            "  on u.id = gm.user_id" +
            " inner join Groups g" +
            "  on gm.group_id = g.id" +
            " inner join GroupAuthorities ga" +
            "  on ga.group_id = g.id" +
            " inner join Roles r2" +
            "  on ga.role_id = r2.id" +
            " inner join hrt02_employee_name em" +
            "  on em.id = u.id" +
            " where u.username = :username")
    public Users findRoleByUsername(@Param("username") String username);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the attempt of jpql query?

Comment: Hi @Andronicus, I have updated my post. See Update 1, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to cast it to `User`, you would have to construct it, not `u.username, r2.authority`. Secondly you need to fetch what you're using to avoid `LazyInitializationException`:

```
@Query("select distinct u from Users u " +
        " left join fetch u.groups g "
        " left join fetch g.roles r " +
        "  ... "
        " where u.username = :username")
public Users findRoleByUsername(@Param("username") String username);
```

It's the beginning, because your entity `Role` has no mapping. You would have to write the same way other entities where the dots are.